# Unexpected Rollback on insert new Project into Database

Tags: mysql, ruby, gitlab

i can read out all projects from gitlab server instance, but on adding a project to build, the database rolls back after insert with following log entries;

```
(0.2ms) BEGIN
Project Exists (0.4ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM projects WHERE projects.name = BINARY         'Namespace / project' LIMIT 1
SQL (0.5ms) INSERT INTO projects (allow_git_fetch, always_build, created_at,     default_ref, gitlab_id, gitlab_url, name, polling_interval, public, scripts,     ssh_url_to_repo, timeout, token, updated_at) VALUES (1, 0, '2013-12-18 14:07:46', 'master',     18, 'http://gitlab.url.de/namespace/project', 'Namespace / project', NULL, 0, 'ls -la',     'git@gitlab.url.de:namespace/project.git', 1800, 'f409267c4f444ee97186daae7d8b15', '2013-    12-18 14:07:46')
(1.8ms) ROLLBACK
```

The Project definitely exists, User Permissions on database are set as described in `installation.md` and a manual insert will affect successfully.

Any Ideas?

Comment: There appears to be erroneous whitespace within the literal value for `updated_at`: `'2013-    12-18 14:07:46'`.  With a strict SQL mode enabled, this would lead to failure of the `INSERT`.